# When are `include directives not needed in Verilog and SystemVerilog?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

Suppose I have a top level file that I pass to my compiler that has:

```
`include "my_defines.sv"
`include "my_component.sv"
```

Inside "my_component.sv" file, I am using some defines from "my_defines.sv", like this:

```
my_variable = `CONSTANT_FROM_MY_DEFINES;
```

The question is the following: do I need to have `` `include "my_defines.sv" `` inside "my_component.sv"? Perhaps this requirement is compiler-specific?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is dependent upon the order in which your source files are compiled.  Because you are referring specifically to`define` macros, which are global, it is required that the macro definitions are compiled before the macro is used.  In your case, you do not need to include "my_defines.sv" inside "my_component.sv" since "my_defines.sv" was already compiled in your top file.

Answer (score 2):

If your "my_defines.sv" has an "include" guard, then it is safe and better to include "my_defines.sv" in all your other files. The "include" guard at the top of "my_defines.sv" will look like this:

```
`ifndef MY_DEFINES_SV
`define MY_DEFINES_SV
// put your own defines here ...
`endif
```

Comment: It will make sure there is not "redefine" error during compile time.

Answer (score 1):

`include` directives like that are like copying and pasting that file into the point where the `include` is. The compiler:

1. Reads the file you give it.
2. When it encounters an include, it reads that file.
3. When it's finished that file it continues the original file.

The result is that the compiler sees one big flat file.

In your example you can use stuff from `my_defines` in `my_component` because it appears earlier.

The problem with doing a lot of this is that eventually you'll end up with conflicts. Maybe two things reference each other (which include comes first), two things use the same name (clashing definitions), or multiple things have the same include statement (multiple definitions of the same thing).

Packages solve those problems. Once things start getting a little more complex, look into them.

Answer (score 0):

you have to include `include "my_defines.sv in my_component.sv...

best practice is add all include in one pkg and add that pkg to each of file.

Answer (score -1):

Macro definitions only persist across files but only to the end of the translation unit.  Simulators must support two different methods of assigning source files to translation units and it's hard to get `include files full of `defines to compile correctly in both methods.

It is better use parameters or const variables for constants.  Since parameters and constants follow normal scoping rules you can safely include them in every file/scope that needs them.  Then it doesn't matter how the code is broken into translation units, it always compiles.  I think it is easier to find the definitions when you're browsing the code because the `include is probably in the same file instead of off in some other unrelated file.